# flutter - Hide sliverappbar when scrolling starts

Tags: flutter, dart, sliverappbar

I want to hide the app bar and the widget at the bottom right away as soon as the screen scrolls. Also, I want to show what I hid as soon as I scroll to the top.

Also, because I have to put a widget under the Appbar, the widget is located in the bottom, and I put the tabbar under the Sliver Persistent Header widget.

The way I did it is to scroll as high as the app bar to hide it.

- The code I wrote

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          key: _nestedScrollViewGlobalKey,
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
                elevation: 0.0,
                title: Text('123123213'),
                floating: true,
                pinned: false,
                snap: true,
                // forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                expandedHeight: (BDSStyle.appBarHeight * 2),
                toolbarHeight: (BDSStyle.appBarHeight * 2),
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: BDSStyle.appBarHeight,
                    color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.4),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: true,
                delegate: TabBarDelegate(_tabController),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: _tabBarView(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  class TabBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final TabController tabController;

  const TabBarDelegate(this.tabController);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return BDSTabBar(
      controller: tabController,
      tabs: List.generate(PlaceCategory.values.length, (index) {
        return PlaceCategory.values[index].koreanName;
      }),
      isScrollable: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => BDSStyle.tabBarHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => BDSStyle.tabBarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

- video link

[Code Execution Image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/59527787/204978717-603b7f2c-73c9-463c-a330-683dfda69d5e.mp4)

[The way I want to implement it](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/59527787/204979121-3d36732e-108b-4cc1-8497-cbe3fb16a219.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

May be this code may help you.

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child:  Scaffold(
        body:  NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
               SliverAppBar(
                title: Text("Application"),
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                snap: true,
                bottom:  TabBar(
                  tabs: <Tab>[
                     Tab(text: "T"),
                     Tab(text: "B"),
                  ], // <-- total of 2 tabs
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body:  TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'T Tab',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  )),
              Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'B Tab',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the contents of TabBarView should be able to scroll indefinitely, so I think it will be difficult to apply it to me. Also, I want the code that the Appbar hides as soon as I scroll to the top.